# MVC5 problems with DropDownList and view model

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

So I have a simple database table in the form of ID, EmployeeID, date etc. Which creates a normal model:

```
public partial class WorkItem
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public int EmployeeID { get; set; }
    public int LocationID { get; set; }
    [DataType( DataType.Date )]
    [Display( Name = "Start date" )]
    public System.DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
```

My problem occurs when I need to augment the functionality of this model and so I create a view model to group work items on a weekly basis.

```
public class WeeklyWorkItemsViewModel
{
    public WorkItem WorkItemMonday { get; set; }
    public WorkItem WorkItemTuesday { get; set; }
```

All works perfectly well for the DateTime field in my view (which is bound to the view model):

```
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor( model => model.WorkItemMonday.StartDate, "Week start date", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" } )
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor( model => model.WorkItemMonday.StartDate, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } } )
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor( model => model.WorkItemMonday.StartDate, "", new { @class = "text-danger" } )
        </div>
    </div>
```

The problem occurs trying to bind the dropdownlilst, it gets populated correctly  but the changes are not seen in the controller.

```
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor( model => model.WorkItemMonday.EmployeeID, "EmployeeID", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" } )
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.Hidden( "selectedEmployee" )
            @Html.DropDownList( "EmployeeID", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" } )
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor( model => model.WorkItemMonday.EmployeeID, "", new { @class = "text-danger" } )
        </div>
    </div>
```

The StartDate **is** updated in the controller.

After mucho head scratching, I finally had to get around this using:

```
@Html.Hidden( "selectedEmployee" )
```

And updating this in JQuery. I did try using @html.DropDownListFor but no joy so far.
Can anyone see what's wrong before I pull ALL my hair out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You model does not contain a property named `EmployeeID`. But it does have ones named `WorkItemMonday.EmployeeID` and `WorkItemTuesday.EmployeeID`.

Stop using `DropDownList()` and use the strongly typed `DropDownListFor()` method so that you correctly bind to your model properties.

Modify you view model to include a property for the `SelectList`

```
public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> EmployeeList { get; set; }
```

and populate it in the GET method before you pass the model to the view. Then in the view use

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.WorkItemMonday.EmployeeID, Model.EmployeeList, new { @class = "form-control" })
....
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.WorkItemTuesday.EmployeeID, Model.EmployeeList, new { @class = "form-control" })
```

which will correct generate the `name="WorkItemMonday.EmployeeID"` and `name="WorkItemTuesday.EmployeeID"` attributes so that they will bind to your model when you post.

Comment: @Yvette, Its been a long time since I have worked with ListView/WPF so I don't feel I can help